# Adapt to json syntax

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, highcharts

I'm using the WebApi in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm trying to pass correct json to a HighStock chart.

The json syntax is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/flags-general/).

Specifically it's this part I'm having trouble creating:

```
[{
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 25),
                title : 'H',
                text : 'Euro Contained by Channel Resistance'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 3, 28),
                title : 'G',
                text : 'EURUSD: Bulls Clear Path to 1.50 Figure'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 4),
                title : 'F',
                text : 'EURUSD: Rate Decision to End Standstill'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 5),
                title : 'E',
                text : 'EURUSD: Enter Short on Channel Break'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 6),
                title : 'D',
                text : 'Forex: U.S. Non-Farm Payrolls Expand 244K, U.S. Dollar Rally Cut Short By Risk Appetite'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 6),
                title : 'C',
                text : 'US Dollar: Is This the Long-Awaited Recovery or a Temporary Bounce?'
            }, {
                x : Date.UTC(2011, 4, 9),
                title : 'B',
                text : 'EURUSD: Bearish Trend Change on Tap?'
            }]
```

How can I control wether single quotes should surround a value? I have all relevant data, the question is just about transforming the data into this json.

Comment: Why arent you just using the `JavaScriptSerializer` or `DataContractJsonSerializer` classes? They output Json for you. Plus, JSON values should be surrounded by quotes, instead of single quotes.

Comment: @Tejs Yes, I can create an object with properties x and title, but that will still render x with quotes.

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the JSON-helper??? 
[JSON method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json.aspx)

Comment: Is Json available on the ApiController?

Comment: @BridgettheMidget: you can use it in any action method of any controller.